# AVAudioInputNode permission

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

This might seem like a really basic question but I'm struggling to find the answer. As far as I'm aware AVAudioInputNode has been available since iOS 8 and it can be used to record from the microphone on an iPhone for example.

I know previously I would use AVAudioRecorderSession to request permission to record and inspect if I had permission etc. What I'm struggling with is seeing how to request and check permission when using AVAudioEngine.

So in something like the below, how would I go about doing this?

```
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func recordPressed(sender:AnyObject) {
        try! startRecording()
    }

    func startRecording() throws{
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, withOptions: .NotifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else { fatalError("Audio engine has no input node") }

        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormatForBus(0)

        inputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in

        }

        audioEngine.prepare()

        try audioEngine.start()


    }

}
```

I've noticed that the microphone privacy message can be set in the plist and calling audioEngine.inputNode seems to present this message. But I still can't see where to check if that permission has been granted. If I add

```
   if (audioSession.recordPermission() == AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted){

    }else{
        print("No permission")
    }
```

directly after the `guard let inputNode` line it presents the message but always tells me that permission isn't granted before I've even responded to the alert.

What's the best way to go about this? Should I just fall back to using the audioSession methods first? For what it's worth a lot of this was lifted from the WWDC code around speechRecognizer. I just can't see where they are handling the mic permission

In fact it doesn't always seem to present the alert to request permissions. What am I missing here as the examples I've found seem to skip this permission step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so looking the docs I found this:

> Recording audio requires explicit permission from the user. The first time your app’s audio session attempts to use an audio input
>   route while using a category that enables recording, the system
>   automatically prompts the user for permission. You can explicitly ask
>   earlier by calling this method. Until the user grants your app
>   permission to record, your app can record only silence.
>
> This method always returns immediately, but the response block awaits
>   user input if the user has not previously granted or denied permission
>   to record in your app.
>
> When a user responds to a recording permission prompt for your app,
>   the system remembers the choice. If the user has denied recording
>   permission, they can reenable it in Settings > Privacy > Microphone.

So it looks like it's doing it automatically when first trying to use the microphone, but ideally I should ask this permission upfront